# If true then insert event

Tags: sql-server-2014, insert, condition, event

I have an insert statement that inserts events into a table. I need it to NOT insert if these events contain specific words or even specific username executing the event. Thought this would be easy but it's not working at all. Tried different techniques including adding the if statement before the insert but no go
something like this

`IF SUSER_SNAME() not like '%someuser%' OR CURRENT_USER NOT like '%anotheruser%'
    Begin
       INSERT DBA_DB.dbo.Events 
        (...)
       Select 
        Events
    END`

tried different variations but cannot filter inserts. So many example online but they are all referring to NOT EXISTS when checking a value already in the table. 
I need to check the values of events, filter them out, and then insert.

Any thoughts?
Thanks

SQL2014

Comment: what rdms system are you using and how exactly are you trying to do this?

Comment: Try changing your `OR` to `AND`  - `IF SUSER_SNAME() not like '%someuser%' AND CURRENT_USER NOT like '%anotheruser%'`

Comment: SQL2014. What do you mean how exactly? I am using SSMS if that's what you mean. How is not working at the moment...

Comment: OMG Can it really be AND/Or issue. Didn't even check the logic at all.

Comment: YUP That did it @scott-hodgin 
` IF SUSER_SNAME() not like '%user1%' AND SUSER_SNAME() NOT like '%user2%' `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing your `OR` to `AND` - `IF SUSER_SNAME() not like '%someuser%' AND CURRENT_USER NOT like '%anotheruser%'`.